# css background size zooming?

Tags: html, css, background, size, zooming

anyway to do css background-size:cover; with zooming 120%?

I tried many time but still not working..

background-size:cover; have a grey border on top/bottom

how to remove the grey border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css:

```
    html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#full-screen-background-image {
  z-index: -999;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  color: #333;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <img alt="full screen background image" src="/background.jpg" id="full-screen-background-image" /> 
  <div id="wrapper">
    <p>Content goes here...</p>
  </div>
</body>
```